Edit or cancel other people's meeting room locations in Outlook 365
Like just about every company in the world we have multiple meeting rooms that people can book via Office 365. Of course people don't deal with these perfectly; meetings for 2 people are booked in the large rooms and meetings that don't take place aren't always cancelled. Sometimes we even have urgent meetings that require other things to be cancelled. Because we deal with a lot of part-timers, the 'proper' route of asking people to fix things isn't always practical.
I'm looking into a way for our Office Managers to shuffle things around. They need to be able to:

remove rooms from a meeting organized by others
change the room of a meeting organized by others

Currently everyone within the organisation can see each other's meeting title and location (unless set to 'private') and we would like to not give our Office Managers more access to other people's calendars than that (EU Privacy Laws apply). Is there any way to do this?
Talked to our IT provider, but the only solution they gave was 'full access for office managers'.
